# TypeScript Angular project : use undefined or null for properties in classes?

Tags: angular, typescript, null, undefined

I've an Angular 6 project, and my question is what's the best way to define a nullable property on a model class?

**Option 1** : use the `?` operator

```
export class ProductModel {
    public name?: string;
}
```

**Option 2** : define the property as **string** and as **null**

```
export class ProductModel {
    public name: string | null;
}
```

Note that I've set `"strictNullChecks": true` in the `tsconfig.json`.

Maybe it's just a preference, but if someone can help me providing some background tips ans tricks or a reference article?

Answer (score 3):

With `strictNullChecks` enabled `name?: string;` name is of type `string | undefined`.

Two examples in the question have not only slightly different syntax but also produce different results:

```
type WithOptional = {
    name?: string;
}

type WithNullable = {
    name: string | null;
}

const withOptional: WithOptional = {}; // no error: name is optional 
withOptional.name = null; // error: null is not assignable to string | undefined

const withNullable: WithNullable = {}; // error: name is missing
withNullable.name = undefined // error: undefined is not assingable to string | null
```

If you want the name to be both optional and nullable you can define it as `name?: string | null;`